# How to format a JavaScript date object using Intl.DateTimeFormat

Tags: javascript, date

I am trying to show a date in a string format like it's done in PHP (using date()).

```
let checkoutDate = new Date();

var formatter = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-us', {
  weekday: 'long',
  year: 'numeric',
  month: 'numeric',
  day: 'numeric',
  hour: 'numeric',
  minute: 'numeric',
  second: 'numeric',
  fractionalSecondDigits: 3,
  hour12: true,
  timeZone: 'UTC'
});

console.log(formatter.format(checkoutDate));
```

The output is : `Friday, 3/13/2020, 2:15:03 PM`
How do I get something like this : `Friday, 13th March 2020` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's my version of this, you can use **formatToParts()** function to get them by part assuming you will be using the same format every time, and then get them by object array so that you can create your own format allowing you to add custom text. Although it would be much more easier and efficient if you will use some other Date formatter.

```
let checkoutDate = new Date();
var th = 'th';
var formatter = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-us', {
  weekday: 'long',
  year: 'numeric',
  month: 'long',
  day: 'numeric',
  fractionalSecondDigits: 3,
  timeZone: 'UTC'
});
var formatted = formatter.formatToParts(checkoutDate);

var day = formatted[4].value;
var wr = checker(day);

console.log(wr);
console.log(formatted[0].value+ ',', day +wr, formatted[2].value, formatted[6].value);

function checker(x){
    if (x > 3 && x < 21) return 'th';
    switch (x % 10) {
        case 1:  return "st";
        case 2:  return "nd";
        case 3:  return "rd";
        default: return "th";
    }
}
//output Friday, 13th March 2020
```

Comment: What if its 22nd or 1st ?

Comment: if you insist on doing it this way then you can simply add a checker for those days to change between th and nd

Comment: @PlanBuildr i've added the checker btw

Comment: Thanks for the function. I was wondering why this is not like PHP where we can control most of the date.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this way:

```
var isoString = new Date().toISOString();
var options = { weekday: 'long', year: 'numeric', month: 'long', day: 'numeric' };
var date = new Date(isoString);
var americanDate = new Intl.DateTimeFormat("en-US", options).format(date);
console.log(americanDate); //Friday, March 13, 2020
```

Using `moment.js`  you can do better date-time format.

Comment: I second the recommendation of `moment.js` if your use case involves a lot of date and time manipulation

Comment: @ChrisBrenberg you are right. but if you want to match exactly, Friday, 13th March 2020, you might have been user 3rd parties library.

Comment: Moment js is deprecated. Use date-fns instead.